# Why does ShowChanges in SVN show me .cache files and DLL files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I open the ShowChanges dialog in SVN it displays a bunch of unversioned .cache files and a bunch of DLL files. How do I prevent it from displaying these files. I should only see .cs files that I realy modified, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It's showing you the files because they exist and TortoiseSVN doesn't know what to do with them.

If you don't want them versioned (and if they're built from items that you're already versioning (the DLLs) or have no need to share/keep versioned (the cache files), ignore them by setting `svn:ignore` appropriately.

Comment: We also use SVN at work and I don't remember ever having to do this at work. If I move them to the ignore-on-commit list, they appear in the ShowChanges dialog at the bottom of the list in the ignore-on-commit section. But at work, when I do ShowChanges the DLLs don't appear anywhere. What am I doing at work that I'm not doing at home?

Comment: Look at the `svn:ignore` properties (not the `ignore-on-commit` list), and the global ignore list in your client configuration.

Comment: I'm new to SVN, how do I look at svn:ignore? I added *.dll to the global ignore list, but they still appear. I tried deleting them but they still appear on the list with a deleted status.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice checkbox in the commit dialog named "Show unversioned files".

In the check-for-modifications dialog however there's a whole group of checkboxes under "Items to show", one of them labeled "Unversioned".